# .Net Core RabbitMq.Client channel.BasicQos does not working

Tags: .net, .net-core, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMq.Client 5.1 for a .net core project. I'm trying to process messages from only one consumer ten by ten instead of one by one. I read some documentations and I think that my solution is setting prefetch count correctly. (Without increasing consumer count)

I tried code below but still messages are blocking the thread and being processed one by one.

Also I tired EventBasicConsumer but could not achieve my goal.

```
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                using (channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {

                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "test", true, false, false, null);
                channel.BasicQos(0, 10, false);

                var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);


                consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
                {

                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                    Console.WriteLine(" [x]Upload Received {0}", message);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);

                };



                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "test",
                                     autoAck: true,
                                     consumer: consumer);


                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Received` event only delivers one message at a time to your code - how could it deliver more with a single `model` event handler argument? If you then sleep, you only delay when `Received` will be raised again since you've blocked the thread on which the events are raised. Thus, you should process your messages in other threads or Tasks.

Even though `Received` is raised one-message-at-a-time, RabbitMQ will deliver 10 messages to your consumer. They are sitting in the TCP buffer and .NET library memory buffers up until the point the `Received` event is raised.

You can prove this by sleeping longer and checking the Management interface. You will see that there are 10 unacknowledged messages in that queue.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I think I misunderstood prefetch logic. I should change the message handling implementation.